# Inequality with a sum and factorial

Tags: inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients, induction

For a homework assignment we have the following question that I'm stuck on.
Let $ 0 \leq y \leq 1 $ be given. $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, define $ \displaystyle S_m(y)=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}y^k$.
Prove by mathematical induction: $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, \: P(m):\: S_m(y) \leq (m+1)!$

The case for $m=1$ is easy: $S_1(y)=\displaystyle S_1(y)=\sum_{k=0}^1 \binom{1}{k}y^k=\binom{1}{0} + \binom{1}{1}y= 1+y \leq (1+1)!=2$ since $y \in [0,1]$. Hence, P(1) is true.

But after here I'm stuck. I thought I had the answer by assuming that $S_m(y)$ is maximised $\Longleftrightarrow y=1$ and using $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{M+1} \binom{M+1}{k} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^M \binom{M}{k}+ \binom{M+1}{M+1}=\sum_{k=0}^M \binom{M}{k} + 1 \overset{Ind. \over Hyp.}{\leq} (M+1)!+1 < (M+2)(M+1)!=((M+1)+1)!$.

But one of my classmates pointed out that I made a mistake, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{M+1} \binom{M+1}{k} \not = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^M \binom{M}{k}+ \binom{M+1}{M+1}$ but $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{M+1} \binom{M+1}{k} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^M \binom{M+1}{k}+ \binom{M+1}{M+1}$. And now I'm stuck.

Does somebody have some advice for me? As it is homework, I'd prefer no full solutions because I have to do it myself one day!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know (officially) the binomial theorem?

Comment: I presume you mean that for $ k \leq n, \binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$?

Comment: No, I meant the formula for $(a+b)^n$.

Comment: I see. Let $a=b=1$ $\Rightarrow 2^m= \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k}$ and then use induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re going to use the fact that it’s maximized at $y=1$, just use the binomial theorem to conclude that

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k=2^m$$

and do the easy induction to show that $2^m\le(m+1)!$ for $m\in\Bbb N$.

**Added:** If you want to stay closer to your approach, use the fact that

$$\binom{M+1}k=\binom{M}k+\binom{M}{k-1}$$

to express $\sum_{k=0}^{M+1}\binom{M+1}k$ in terms of $\sum_{k=0}^M\binom{M}k$.

Comment: Can I just say that it's maximized for $y=1$ without further clarification?

Comment: @Nigel: You probably ought to mention that each $y^k$ is a non-decreasing function of $y$ on $[0,1]$ and that the binomial coefficients are all positive, so that $S_m(y)$ is a sum of non-decreasing functions and therefore itself non-decreasing on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I think I've got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nigel: You’re very welcome.